# Can't resolve some of the deprecated methods of Spring Security like and() and formLogin()

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am creating a project using Spring and I am facing some issues.
I see many of the methods have been deprecated and I have updated them by searching on net but I am facing trouble with "and()" and "formLogin()".
Someone please help.

Here's my code in which I have updated some of the deprecated methods :

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .requestMatchers(
                "/registration**",
                        "/js/**",
                        "/css/**",
                        "/img/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .and()
                        .logout(Customizer.withDefaults())
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                        .permitAll()

        )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```

But it has error in "and()" and "formLogin()" and I couldn't figure out how to solve this.
This is the error its showing :

> 'and()' is deprecated and marked for removal

> 'formLogin()' is deprecated and marked for removal

Please fix it.

Comment: That are warnings, no errors. You should find the information how it is replaced in the javadoc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Migration Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/index.html) and [What’s New in Spring Security 6.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/whats-new.html) and also [Deprecated-List](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/deprecated-list.html), you configuration should look so:

```
 @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers(
                "/registration**",
                "/js/**",
                "/css/**",
                "/img/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated());
    http.formLogin(fL -> fL.loginPage("/login").permitAll());
    http.logout(lOut -> {
      lOut.invalidateHttpSession(true)
          .clearAuthentication(true)
          .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
          .permitAll();
    });
    http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
  }
```

For more information i really suggest you to read\check the above attached references.